# How to integrate Google Calendar using Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, google-calendar-api

I have developed an application using adobe Flex 3 as frontend and  Java as backend. The application is related to CRM. So i need to integrate Google Calender into my application using flex 3.

Please anyone give me the steps to integrate this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for a backend? There are python, Java, and .Net Libraries for the latest google calendar api: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html

Or you could fall back to the 1.0 api and use php or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following:

http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/tag/actionscript-library-for-google-calendar/